# Need to force relogin after 30 minutes of idle time

Tags: 12.04, login, logout, guest-session

I've rebuilt the guest computer in the hotel lobby, and we'd like to implement a 30-minute session timeout without cutting guest sessions short. Is there a way to have the computer log itself out of the guest account 30 minutes after detecting keystroke activity, then log back into the guest account after 15 seconds?